# Need information about using multi service-worker in a domain

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I have a PWA website and has my own `service-worker.js` file for caching. For some reasons, I want to use a push notification service on my web site. I should know the answers to these questions:

1) How can I use multi-service workers in website root dir?

2) Can I use one service worker file and put two `importscript` of two service workers on it?

3) Can I use a fake scope for registering service worker? (I mean use a scope and it's not in my website path.)

4) If I use `importscript`, Is caching still available for my old users?

I tried to use one service-worker in root dir of website and use `importscript` into this service worker file like this:

```js
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
importScripts('service-worker.js');
```

I've got a push notification and everything is ok but I don't know my old user cached file is still available?

Also, I tried to use register both of them with registering with scope but `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` (`promise`) for subscribing is always in `pending`:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {scope: '/fake'})
        .then((registration) => {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful.', registration)
          return navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('ServiceWorker registration failed.', error)
        })
```

```js
console:

navigator.serviceWorker.ready = Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question :

1) How can I use multi-service workers in website root dir?

You can only have one service worker register by site on a specified scope : so only one on `/` scope,  but you can add a service worker on each scope on your site (i.e: one on `/` and one on `/user`)
But you can merge 2 service worker in one if you need it.

2) Can I use one service worker file and put two importscript of two service workers on it?

Yes you can do that, you can put any number of eventListener that you need, they are exectuted in declaration order, but be careful, unless a `require` in javascript, all script import with `importScripts()` share same scope, so they can have some problems if individual script share some variable name.

3) Can I use a fake scope for registering service worker? (I mean use a scope and it's not in my website path.)

You can, but scope of SW determine it's execution context, so it will be load on your computer/phone but it will only be effictive on request in it's scope, if you are on a page under it (`website.com/fake` or `website.com/fake/whateverelse`) or if you call a ressource in this scope (`website.com/fake/style.css`)

4) If I use importscript, Is caching still available for my old users?

It depend on what you do in your `install` and `activate` phase. Installing a new SW, or a new version of it won't clear cache unless you do it explicitely in your code.